# Prove that in an disordered set of 50 numbers, you can always remove 42 numbers in a way that leaves an ordered set of 8 numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I am struggling with a combinatorics problem stated in a title. It has to be said, that the 8-element set we are left after removal of the rest of elements has to be ordered without rearranging the leftover elements. Also, the numbers in the original 50-element set are all unique and the ordered set of 8 can be  sorted both ways, biggest to smallest or smallest to biggest, it doesn't matter.

Even a hint where to start with this question would be welcome, I am completely crushed by this question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.